# How to load nltk stopwords or words from local disk

Tags: download, nltk

I would need to load nltk 'words' data from local disk. In the notebook my code looks like the following,

```
import nltk
nltk.data.path.append("/data") # Setting path here
nltk.corpus.words.words()
```

But I am getting error as follows,

```
LookupError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nltk/corpus/util.py in __load(self)
     83                 try:
---> 84                     root = nltk.data.find(f"{self.subdir}/{zip_name}")
     85                 except LookupError:

/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nltk/data.py in find(resource_name, paths)
    582     resource_not_found = f"\n{sep}\n{msg}\n{sep}\n"
--> 583     raise LookupError(resource_not_found)
    584 

LookupError: 
**********************************************************************
  Resource words not found.
  Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:

  >>> import nltk
  >>> nltk.download('words')
  
  For more information see: https://www.nltk.org/data.html

  Attempted to load corpora/words.zip/words/

  Searched in:
    - '/home/my_user_name/nltk_data'
    - '/anaconda3/nltk_data'
    - '/anaconda3/share/nltk_data'
    - '/anaconda3/lib/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/lib/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/lib/nltk_data'
    - '/data'
```

I used the manual installation part from here, https://www.nltk.org/data.html
But, instead of NLTK_DATA, I wanted to set the path from the notebook.

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is completely frustrating that such a popular package nltk gives misleading messages.

The following message is just wrong!

###### Attempted to load corpora/words.zip/words/

It is not trying to load corpora from words.zip with folder words. It was attempting to load from nltk_data/corpora/words.

###### Attempted to load nltk_data/corpora/words/

so, solution is to add correct path manually as follows,
nltk.data.path.append("./data/nltk_data")

and then, put the unzipped file inside this, for example 'words' folder. And then access words as,

```
nltk.corpus.words.words()
```